# WCF - Is that good to use "DataSet" for transferring data through NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, memory-management, dataset, buffer

One of by service contract passes a Huge `DataSet` to the Client. I am using `BufferedTranfer` mode.

In very rare cases I have more data to be send, because of this reason I am in a confusion to change the TransportMode to Streamed.

Is that good practice to use `"DataSet"` for transfer data through `NetTcpBinding`  ?

Any alternatives to `DataSets` ?

Comment: No it's not good practice. The `DataSet` has a significant amount of overhead which needs to be serialized and transferred, too - not really what you want. You should use business objects and/or collections (lists) of business objects instead.

Comment: DataSet (and DataTable) are very hard to use - they represent the relational model (rows and columns) and they don't work well in a .NET app. They don't offer any type safety, they don't offer any properties discoverable via intellisense - you just have to know their internal structure (what columns are present and what they mean and what data they hold). DataSets are really messy and inconvenient to work with. Especially when doing WCF - **stop using DataSets!** - use **real** .NET objects instead - much easier to work with, type-safe, discoverable!

Comment: Thanks ! Ok... What is the best replacement option ? a List<Employee> or any other data structures in .net like Dictionary or ... ?

Comment: Yes, `List<Employee>` would work just nicely.

Comment: DataSets CAN be strong typed - you can define them ahead of time. You can even develop them programatically, until the structure is right for you, then export the schema into your project and then it's accessible in a fully type safe version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please, do not return datasets from a WCF service.

For information why see: [Returning DataSets from WebServices is the Spawn of Satan and Represents All That Is Truly Evil in the World,](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

Comment: +1 I was searching for that link - sums it up very nicely indeed !

Answer (score 0):

In a 3tier application we do return DataSets from a WCF service layer, successfully and without hitting the performance (too much). Reason is: our entities of our SQL database can be changed via meta data at any time. A client can request the meta data information of an entity (columns, types, sizes, nullable etc).

A request to the service names the entity and retrieves the current setup of columns specified in the meta data as DataSet. This allows full flexibility which is not the case with a hard coded object model.

Answer (score -2):

Before sending data across platforms/network, it is advisable for them to be serialized and even encrypted for secure reasons into some sort of formats, and XML seems most promising for large chunks of data. I hear it works better but I never try it myself.