# Error while deserialization in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, deserialization

I have a class Template and it contains some properties some of which are of DataSet.

I have made

```
KnownType[typeof(Template)]
```

I have created an

```
[Operation Contract] 
SerializableDictionary<string,Template> GetDicTemplate = New SerializableDictionary<string,Template>();
```

My code for SerializableDictionary goes as follows:

```
namespace Somthing
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("dictionary")]

    public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>: Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
    {
        public SerializableDictionary()
        {

        }
        public SerializableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            : base(comparer)
        {

        }

        public SerializableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            : base(dictionary, comparer)
        {

        }


        protected SerializableDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
        {

        }

        #region IXmlSerializable Members

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {

            return null;

        }



        public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {

            XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));

            XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));



            bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;

            reader.Read();



            if (wasEmpty)

                return;



            while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {

                reader.ReadStartElement("item");



                reader.ReadStartElement("key");

                TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);

                reader.ReadEndElement();



                reader.ReadStartElement("value");

                TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

                reader.ReadEndElement();



                this.Add(key, value);



                reader.ReadEndElement();

                reader.MoveToContent();

            }

            reader.ReadEndElement();

        }



        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {

            XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));

            XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));



            foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
            {

                writer.WriteStartElement("item");



                writer.WriteStartElement("key");

                keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);

                writer.WriteEndElement();



                writer.WriteStartElement("value");

                TValue value = this[key];

                valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);

                writer.WriteEndElement();



                writer.WriteEndElement();

            }

        }

        #endregion

        public virtual object Clone()
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Well when i am deserializing it I am getting error pointing out that **element is an invalid xmlnodetype with NetDispatcherFaultException**.

I tried to debug it and what i found that it was pointing on one of my Template Class properties, which was of type DataSet.

In order to resolve this I madea new Class MyDataContract in which i put getter_setter for DataSet, but still facing the same issue.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: it is a bad idea to send the whole dataset through WCF, you'll better check this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790309/wcf-is-that-good-to-use-dataset-for-transferring-data-through-nettcpbinding

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including exception type, message, traceback and inner exception (if any)

Comment: Also, can you give a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, ideally in a console app?

Comment: I believe the `DataSet` has to be named in order to be serialized.